# auth()->user() is null in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I just update the composer to Laravel 5.2 and not able to view password protected pages. Basically below line of code is not working.

```
auth()->user()
```

Can somebody suggest why this is not working ?

Comment: Did you update your config/auth.php configuration file with the following: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/config/auth.php ?

Comment: Yes, The only change is : `'model' => App\Models\User\User_Model::class,` instead of `model' => App\User::class,`

Comment: What does `attempt()` (or `login()` or whatever you're using) return when you try to authenticate the user?

Comment: `Auth::user()` is not null in `handleUserWasAuthenticated` method in `Trait AuthenticatesUsers`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 Auth not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548061/laravel-5-2-auth-not-working)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure any routes that require sessions (which Auth uses) are behind the **'web'** middleware group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // your routes
});
```

This is a change that is new to 5.2. By default routes do not have this middleware stack applied. The web middleware group sets the session store, cookies, and csrf protection.

Comment: Great answer. I'd upgraded to 5.2 and my package controllers were suddenly not able to find the authenticated user.

Answer (score 7):

In Laravel 5.2 upgrade, routes that use **Auth** must be in web middleware group.

I solved this problem in **app/Http/Kernel.php** moving **web** middleware groups to **global** middlewares.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
];
```

Comment: I got same issue in 5.3.6 and your suggestion solved my issue. Thank You. +1

Answer (score 5):

May it will help someone else. But don't forget to see what the `guard` you are using. For example, for admins you may not default guard, but create your own. Don't forget it. Calling `\Auth::guard($guard)->user()`

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to blindly add middleware to routes, you simply need to add the classes that manage cookies & sessions to the relevant middleware group (`api` in my case). For me those classes where:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

This is how my `App\Http\Kernel::$middleWare` variable ended up looking:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class
    ],
];
```

*Using Laravel 5.3*