# Laravel 5.2 Auth not Working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

As you guys know Laravel 5.2 was released a few days ago. I am trying this new version. I made a new project using the following command on CLI:

```
laravel new testapp
```

As per [documentation of Authentication Quickstart](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart), I followed the following command  to scaffold  routes and views of authentication:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

It worked fine. Registration is working fine. But I am facing problem in Login. After login I tested following in route.php file:

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
    dd( Auth::user());
    return view('welcome');
});
```

`Auth::user()` is returning `null` and also `Auth::check()` and `Auth::guest()` are not working appropriately. I have tried same thing again and again two three times by making new projects but couldn't get the correct results.

Below is the complete `route.php`

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    dd( Auth::());
    return view('welcome');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Can anyone help me? or Is anyone facing the same problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: are you using the middleware group `web` in your route group ? Please post all your routes.php

Comment: @Moppo added above in the question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 introduces the [**middleware groups**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups) concept: you can specify that one or more middleware belongs to a group, and you can apply a middleware group to one or more routes

By default Laravel 5.2 defines a group named `web`, used to group the middleware handling session and other http utilities:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
],
```

So, **if you want session handling, you should use this middleware group** for all the routes in which you want to use authentication:

```
Route::group( [ 'middleware' => ['web'] ], function () 
{
    //this route will use the middleware of the 'web' group, so session and auth will work here         
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd( Auth::user() );
    });       
});
```

**UPDATE FOR LARAVEL VERSION >= 5.2.27**

As of Laravel `5.2.27` version, all the routes defined in `routes.php` are using by default the `web` middleware group. That is achieved in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` :

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web'
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

So you don't need anymore to add manually the `web` middleware group to your routes.

Anyhow, if you want to use the default authentication for a route, you still need bind the `auth` middleware to the route

Comment: This makes so much more sense to me, after the initial mental hurdle of "no you don't need the `auth` middleware to make Auth work, you need the `web` middleware"...