# Laravel auth not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm having problems authenticating users using Laravel's builtin auth system.

I have a users table with a `username` and `password` fields. I've set up routes with the `web` middleware to process the authentication and added my protected routes with the `auth` middleware.

What's strange is that authentication seems to work fine but if i try to access a protected route i get redirected back to the login page.

I checked the `$errors` in the login page and, if i supply a bad username/password combo i get the standard error message:

> These credentials do not match our records.

If i supply valid credentials i get no errors but i'm still redirected to the login page.

I activated Laravel's debugbar to try and track down the problem. With invalid credentials i can see two requests: the first do the login action and the second back to the login form. With valid credentials i can see three requests: the first to the login action, the second to the protected action where it should go after a successful authentication and then a third one back to the login page.

Seems to me that the authentication info is not being stored. With debugbar i can see there is a **login_web_59ba36addc2b2f94...** variable but with null contents.

Am i missing something here? Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? If it's 5.2 check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548061/laravel-5-2-auth-not-working/34548115#34548115). Also, please post your routes files

Comment: Yes it's 5.2. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Probably you should use the 'web' group as shown in the link above

Comment: I am using the 'web' group and created a new 'auth' group for protected routes.

Comment: Laravel has already an 'auth' middleware, try to use it in a route and check if it works

Comment: Yes i am awere. I am using it!

Comment: Please, post your route file