# Show login page while unauthorized users try to view PDF files in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, file, security

In my application, PDF upload option is there. The uploaded PDF files stored in media/pdfs directory.

For ex. http://localhost/xxx/media/pdfs/samplePDF.pdf

Now this link is accessable for unauthorized users also. I want to avoid that. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You define  a route/route-group to serve your files from this `pdf` folder and then apply `auth` middleware to this route or route group

Comment: How to apply auth middleware to the url http://localhost/xxx/media/pdfs/samplePDF.pdf, because the pdf file name will be dynamic ie, samplePDF.pdf will change.

Comment: When declaring a route, [you can include parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters) associated with a given regular expression (in your case, maybe `/^[a-zA-Z]+\.pdf$/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure Asset/Media Folder through Auth Controller ? Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250454/secure-asset-media-folder-through-auth-controller-laravel-5-2)

Comment: In my application, laravel version is 5.0, the duplicate question you are mentioned above is for laravel 5.2