# Laravel Auth:: attempt is working but auth::user() getting NULL

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new in **Laravel**.

Now I want to use the `middleware`.

So Please help me.

**My code is:**

```
    $input = Input::except('_token');

    if(Auth::attempt($input)){         
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }else{
        return Redirect::to(route('login'))
                ->with('message','Sorry, Wrong Username and password .');
    }
```

The `Auth::attempt` is working perfectly and its redirecting to dashboard as expected.

But when I try to check the `Auth::check` function from the controller its returning the else statement.

```
public function dashboard(){      
    if(Auth::check()){
      return View::make('dashboard');
    }else{
      return "Not logged in";
    }
}
```

**How can I fix the issue ?**

Session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => null,
'secure' => false,
'http_only' => true,
```

Comment: Have u Check error log???

Comment: #Sruthi : Have you try given code?

Comment: Can you share the session config with us? It seems it's session configuration issue as the user exists and that's why Auth::attempt($input) succeeds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 Auth not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548061/laravel-5-2-auth-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using subdomain then change this line below (config/session)

```
'domain' => null,
to

'domain' => '.yourdomain.com',
```

Also if you are using files to store session

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

then check if you have write permission given to storage/framework/sessions directory . you also can try changing database sessions .

Comment: I given 777 permission to storage directory & my env configuration is SESSION_DRIVER=file.. its not working

Comment: Have you checked config/session.php file??

Comment: Can you please  post your Config/Session.php file

Comment: Have you try to set domain with your domain?

Comment: I am developing in local env

Comment: i have same issue but in my case its working in local env but on server same issue

Comment: Are all your routes that need Auth/sessions inside the web middleware group?

Comment: Currently I am not given any middleware to routes

Answer (score 0):

use **auth** middleware on your route for which you are using below controller function

```
public function dashboard(){      
    if(Auth::check()){
      return View::make('dashboard');
    }else{
      return "Not logged in";
    }
}
```