# Laravel Auth - Redirect on Login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have a small Laravel 5.2 project that I'm working on. I've used the built in auth package to handle the login for this proof of concept. However when I login it redirects me to the `/` route even after setting the following.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/specialRoute';
```

Is there anywhere else that I need to set the login to go to `/special route`?

Comment: In which file did you declare such a property?

Comment: Did you override the AuthController with your package?

Comment: do u declare protected $redirectTo = '/specialRoute'; in AuthController.php and do u declare specialRoute in route.php??

Comment: are you using any middleware?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 Auth not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548061/laravel-5-2-auth-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change the default $redirectTo value in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers` trait.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to AuthController

> Auth/AuthController.php

```
protected $redirectPath= '/specialRoute';
```

This redirect path will be used for successful login and successful register.

Overriding the postRegister function should work too. You would do this in your AuthController:

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request)
 {
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));     
    // Now you can redirect!
    return redirect('/specialRoute');
 }
```

More info about redirects if you want to redirect to a route: http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects