# Laravel : Auth::user() returns null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to do **Auth::user()** but before that I must do **Auth::attempt()**  but it always returns false because **the attempt() method  uses ID to look for the user I am are trying to login.** But in my users table I don't have a ID field rather I have user_id field. So is there a way to make the attempt() method use user_id to look up for id in my users table. (Hope I made some sense )

```
if(!Auth::attempt(Request::only(['username','password']))){  //returns false
     return redirect($this->redirectPath);   /// redirect to login page
}else{
     return redirect($this->redirectTo);   /// redirect to user list page
}
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-returns-null-in-laravel-52

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190207/authuser-returns-null-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-returns-null-in-laravel-52?page=0

Comment: I am aware of the methods discussed there but in order to use Auth::user() I first need to login, but in my case i cannot even login because Auth::attempt() is used to authenticate login and it returns false because I don;t have id column in my table ..

Comment: Did you try changing primary key in `User` model? `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'`

Comment: yup .. didn't do any good ..

Comment: Ok, but now chances are there is some problem with `attempt`. Replace `!Auth::attempt(Request::only(['username','password']))` with `!Auth::loginUsingId(1)` and see what happens.

Comment: That's not gonna do any good .. All laravel eloquent model uses Query string like "" SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id= <id> . So, till i change my column name to id in my users table , I cannot use any of { attempt(), find(), loginUsingId()} .. I would have to hard code SQL if I don't want to change my column name

Comment: @username you're doing something wrong. With `attempt` laravel tries to find the model by provided credentials (in this case just `username`, since password will be stripped down), no id. If you try with `loginUsingId` it will use the `primaryKey` of your model (which defaults to `id`, but can be changed).